# SharePoint 2013 workflow sending two emails when task is assigned

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I created a SharePoint 2013 type workflow (using SharePoint 2016) in SharePoint Designer. When a task is assigned then user is receiving two emails. One email is my custom email which I have set in workflow and other is system generated. The other email seems like the one which is sent by SharePoint when you are subscribed to Alerts on a list. But the thing is I haven't done any subscription so why users are receiving this email and how to make it stop?

Screenshot given below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tested this by making a task be assigned to you, and if a task is assigned to you can you verify that _you_ receive two emails (one from the workflow and one list alert), even though _you_ have not subscribed to alerts?  You say that _you_ have not "done any subscription", but it is up to the other users to set up their own alerts, so maybe the user(s) who are receiving two emails have set up the alert subscriptions themselves?

Comment: This is Dev environment and I have just created this new site for testing. So there are no subscriptions before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Workflow Tasks list and go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings, set Send e-mail when ownership is assigned? to No

[image]